# Fibonacci Reverse Calculation?

Tags: python, numpy, fibonacci

I was reading Dr Knotts entries about Binets formula on his fibonacci page
http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html

I entered the formula into an Excel spreadsheet to see how this would work ;

Binet Formula
Fib(n) =  (1.6180339^n – (–0.6180339..)^n) / 2.236067977..

Its fascinating to see how I can enter any number for (n) and see the
correct fibonacci number returned!

I have a question though, I am a newbie computer programmer using
VB and Python and my math skills are average at best but I am very
interest and curious about math and especially fibonacci numbers!

Say I wanted to reverse and change the process.

I have a very large fibonacci number and I want to know what the 
fibonacci number is at a specified position BEFORE it, how would
I compute this, what would the formula be?

So for example I have the 301 st fibo number of ;

359579325206583560961765665172189099052367214309267232255589801

And I want to be able to find what the fibonacci value would be (n) numbers
BEFORE this... so I might want to know what the fibo value would be 50
numbers before or the 251st fibo number.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, not sure if I can deliver a good answer. Since you do not know how big the last Fibonacci was, you can not subtract the solution by some number. You would need to have the Fibonacci numbers stored somewhere at a starting point at least.

I think that the easiest solution would be to build up your Fibonacci sum bit by in a list and stop when you come at the correct large number. Then you just trace back in your list *n* steps and find the solution...

Perhaps a mathematician could give better input to this dilemma :-)